# Error a Partition MySql 5.5

Tags: mysql, partition

I'm trying to create the partition scheme below, however, it's showing an error.

MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(my_date), month(my_date))(
    PARTITION p0   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 1),
    PARTITION p1' at line 2

Is this the best way?
My table is 10k

```
 ALTER TABLE my_table
PARTITION by LIST COLUMNS (year(my_date), month(my_date))(
    PARTITION p0   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 1),
PARTITION p1   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 2),
PARTITION p2   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 3),
PARTITION p3   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 4),
PARTITION p4   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 5),
PARTITION p5   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 6),
PARTITION p6   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 7),
PARTITION p7   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 8),
PARTITION p8   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 9),
PARTITION p9   VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 10),
PARTITION p10  VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 11),
PARTITION p11  VALUES LESS THAN (2010, 12),
PARTITION p12  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 1),
PARTITION p13  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 2),
PARTITION p14  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 3),
PARTITION p15  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 4),
PARTITION p16  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 5),
PARTITION p17  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 6),
PARTITION p18  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 7),
PARTITION p19  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 8),
PARTITION p20  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 9),
PARTITION p21  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 10),
PARTITION p22  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 11),
PARTITION p23  VALUES LESS THAN (2011, 12),
PARTITION p24  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 1),
PARTITION p25  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 2),
PARTITION p26  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 3),
PARTITION p27  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 4),
PARTITION p28  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 5),
PARTITION p29  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 6),
PARTITION p30  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 7),
PARTITION p31  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 8),
PARTITION p32  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 9),
PARTITION p33  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 10),
PARTITION p34  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 11),
PARTITION p35  VALUES LESS THAN (2013, 12),
PARTITION p36  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 1),
PARTITION p37  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 2),
PARTITION p38  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 3),
PARTITION p39  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 4),
PARTITION p40  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 5),
PARTITION p41  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 6),
PARTITION p42  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 7),
PARTITION p43  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 8),
PARTITION p44  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 9),
PARTITION p45  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 10),
PARTITION p46  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 11),
PARTITION p47  VALUES LESS THAN (2014, 12), 
PARTITION p48  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 1),
PARTITION p49  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 2),
PARTITION p50  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 3),
PARTITION p51  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 4),
PARTITION p52  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 5),
PARTITION p53  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 6),
PARTITION p54  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 7),
PARTITION p55  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 8),
PARTITION p56  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 9),
PARTITION p57  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 10),
PARTITION p58  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 11),
PARTITION p59  VALUES LESS THAN (2015, 12),
PARTITION p60  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 1),
PARTITION p61  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 2),
PARTITION p62  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 3),
PARTITION p63  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 4),
PARTITION p64  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 5),
PARTITION p65  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 6),
PARTITION p66  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 7),
PARTITION p67  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 8),
PARTITION p68  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 9),
PARTITION p69  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 10),
PARTITION p70  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 11),
PARTITION p71  VALUES LESS THAN (2016, 12),
PARTITION p72  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 1),
PARTITION p73  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 2),
PARTITION p74  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 3),
PARTITION p75  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 4),
PARTITION p76  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 5),
PARTITION p77  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 6),
PARTITION p78  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 7),
PARTITION p79  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 8),
PARTITION p80  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 9),
PARTITION p81  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 10),
PARTITION p82  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 11),
PARTITION p83  VALUES LESS THAN (2017, 12),
PARTITION p84  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 1),
PARTITION p85  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 2),
PARTITION p86  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 3),
PARTITION p87  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 4),
PARTITION p88  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 5),
PARTITION p89  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 6),
PARTITION p90  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 7),
PARTITION p91  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 8),
PARTITION p92  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 9),
PARTITION p93  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 10),
PARTITION p94  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 11),
PARTITION p95  VALUES LESS THAN (2018, 12),
PARTITION p96  VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 1),
PARTITION p97  VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 2),
PARTITION p98  VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 3),
PARTITION p99  VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 4),
PARTITION p100 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 5),
PARTITION p101 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 6),
PARTITION p102 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 7),
PARTITION p103 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 8),
PARTITION p104 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 9),
PARTITION p105 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 10),
PARTITION p106 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 11),
PARTITION p107 VALUES LESS THAN (2019, 12),
PARTITION p108 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 1),
PARTITION p109 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 2),
PARTITION p110 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 3),
PARTITION p111 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 4),
PARTITION p112 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 5),
PARTITION p113 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 6),
PARTITION p114 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 7),
PARTITION p115 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 8),
PARTITION p116 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 9),
PARTITION p117 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 10),
PARTITION p118 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 11),
PARTITION p119 VALUES LESS THAN (2020, 12),
PARTITION p120 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 1),
PARTITION p121 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 2),
PARTITION p122 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 3),
PARTITION p123 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 4),
PARTITION p124 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 5),
PARTITION p125 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 6),
PARTITION p126 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 7),
PARTITION p127 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 8),
PARTITION p128 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 9),
PARTITION p129 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 10),
PARTITION p130 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 11),
PARTITION p131 VALUES LESS THAN (2021, 12),
PARTITION p132 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 1),
PARTITION p133 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 2),
PARTITION p134 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 3),
PARTITION p135 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 4),
PARTITION p136 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 5),
PARTITION p137 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 6),
PARTITION p138 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 7),
PARTITION p139 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 8),
PARTITION p140 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 9),
PARTITION p141 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 10),
PARTITION p142 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 11),
PARTITION p143 VALUES LESS THAN (2022, 12),
PARTITION p144 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 1),
PARTITION p145 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 2),
PARTITION p146 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 3),
PARTITION p147 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 4),
PARTITION p148 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 5),
PARTITION p149 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 6),
PARTITION p150 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 7),
PARTITION p151 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 8),
PARTITION p152 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 9),
PARTITION p153 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 10),
PARTITION p154 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 11),
PARTITION p155 VALUES LESS THAN (2023, 12),
PARTITION p156 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 1),
PARTITION p157 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 2),
PARTITION p158 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 3),
PARTITION p159 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 4),
PARTITION p160 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 5),
PARTITION p161 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 6),
PARTITION p162 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 7),
PARTITION p163 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 8),
PARTITION p164 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 9),
PARTITION p165 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 10),
PARTITION p166 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 11),
PARTITION p167 VALUES LESS THAN (2024, 12),
PARTITION p168 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 1),
PARTITION p169 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 2),
PARTITION p170 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 3),
PARTITION p171 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 4),
PARTITION p172 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 5),
PARTITION p173 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 6),
PARTITION p174 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 7),
PARTITION p175 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 8),
PARTITION p176 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 9),
PARTITION p177 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 10),
PARTITION p178 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 11),
PARTITION p179 VALUES LESS THAN (2025, 12),
PARTITION p180 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE, MAXVALUE)    
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing range and list partitioning.

If you must partition this table, you probably want to try something like this, [using the `EXTRACT()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract):

```
 PARTITION by RANGE (EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM my_date))
    PARTITION p0   VALUES LESS THAN (201001),
    PARTITION p1   VALUES LESS THAN (201002),
    PARTITION p2   VALUES LESS THAN (201003),
    ...
```

But think it through. There's both a staff and performance cost to adopting partitioning.

- staff cost: often you need to add partitions, years down the line, when your system is in production.
- performance cost: queries sometimes run absurdly slowly because they have to look at multiple partitions, and that takes IO cycles. That kind of performance problem brings you back to ....
- staff cost: you have to figure out what happened to slow your application down.

It can be a pain in the neck.

Partitioning is generally most useful when table sizes become large, that is, at least tens of millions of rows.  Your table of about 10K rows, is (with respect) considered a small table. MySQL and other RDMS systems can handle tables with millions of rows without trouble.

There's no harm in figuring out how partitioning works. But your table is too small for it to help you in production.

Comment: OPS sorry 10 MB rows 10,000,000 -> Grows very fast because it registers each access to the site

Comment: Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function